# script to parse word document

Tags: php, javascript, parsing

I have to get the contents (texts for some exercises) from several word documents (lots of them) and transform them so they can be loaded in a Javascript application.

An example of the contents of these word documents is:

---

1.Text question 1

answer 1
answer 2
answer 3

2.Text **question** 2 with one _ _ _ _ _ _ _ or more.

answer 1
answer 2
answer 3

etc

---

So there's one line with the question, a blank line, and then 3 lines with the possible answers. In the example I've put 2 questions, but there can be 12+ per word document. Please note that in words in the question text could be underlined or bolded. Also there could be blank spaces (represented by several _ characters, with or without spaces in-between).

The output format for these word documents would be something like:

```
var questions = [
{
label : "1.Text question 1",
options : ["answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3"],
answer : [1] //Here I will need to set the right answer, probably manually
},
{
label : "1.Text <strong>question</strong> 2",
options : ["answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3"],
answer : [0] //Here I will need to set the right answer, probably manually
},
etc
];
```

So it's a basic associative array in JS. Please note that the "label" key will hold the text of the questions in html format (so in the example there's a `<strong>` tag to reflect the bold word in the second question).

What I'm looking for is a script that accepts as input a word document like the example and
outputs a JS file also like my output example (if it's a text file that works as well). The scripting languages would be best if it's PHP or Javascript. It's OK if I have to do a little work on the word documents to adapt something to make the script easier.

The main challenge for me with this is how to keep all the text styles (bold, underline, blank spaces...) that the text can have, otherwise transforming them to simple txt files I guess would work...

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: Having you considered saving them as html first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming new lines as described, split at new lines and make choices depending on blank lines, e.g.

```
function parse(str) {
    var a = str.split('\n'), // split input and var everything
        flag = 0, question = -1, qLine = 0, i,
        questions = [];
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) { // loop over lines
        if (!a[i]) {         // if blank line,
            flag = 1 - flag; // flip choice
            qLine = 0;       // reset multi-line counter
        }
        else if (flag === 0) {   // if question line
            if (qLine === 0) {   // if new question
                questions.push({ // add to questions
                    label: a[i],
                    options: [],
                    answer: []
                });
                ++question;      // and increase question count
            } else {             // else multi-line question
                questions[question].label += '\n' + a[i]; // add to label
            }
            ++qLine;             // either way increase multi-line counter
        }
        else if (flag === 1) {   // if answer line
            questions[question].options.push(a[i]);       // add answer
        }
    }
    return questions;
}
```

Then

```
parse('1.Text question 1\n\
\n\
answer 1\n\
answer 2\n\
answer 3\n\
\n\
2.Text question 2 with one _ _ _ _ _ _ _ or more.\n\
\n\
answer 1\n\
answer 2\n\
answer 3\n\
');
/*
[
    {
        "label": "1.Text question 1",
        "options": [
            "answer 1",
            "answer 2",
            "answer 3"
        ],
        "answer": []
    },
    {
        "label": "2.Text question 2 with one _ _ _ _ _ _ _ or more.",
        "options": [
            "answer 1",
            "answer 2",
            "answer 3"
        ],
        "answer": []
    }
]
*/
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. How do I "read" here the formatting of the text? if there are bold words, underlined words, etc...

Comment: @Albert the input string only cares about new lines, if you have any tags in it they'll be sent through exactly as they are.

Comment: well that's my problem... there are no "tags", it's not html, it's a word document. Transforming everything to html would add many more tags that would make your code not to work...